# Fading background banner images, automatically resizable to current width of window

Tags: javascript, css, image, banner, fading

I've been trying to get a nice, smooth banner with fading images.

**Basic concept:**

- 1920px to 1280px width - center of the image stays centered while
  resizing, image doesn't rescale. Height will be a constant.
- It's an archery club website, I'd like to have a banner showing several images of the environment. These images fade in and fade out.
- My current concept website has a horizontal menu bar, which separates the *Header* background from the *Body* background.
- An example would be the RuneScape banner. It has smooth transitions, resizing only the width.

I've tried several tutorials, both fading images with CSS and JS. However, these were only useful to create fading images ontop of the background. I tried to put these fading images ontop of my banner, trying to work around it. After a few hours, it turned out to be one big mess.

Next I tried Maximages - I managed to get everything working, but it only changes my  background. I have no clue how I could use it to change my header, which wraps all of my banner content.

I hope someone could show me other solutions on how to tackle this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to show some kind of "demo"

Comment: The only example I can find at the moment is the Runescape website. Smooth transitions in the banner, resizing width from both ends without rescaling the image.

Answer (score 1):

Create a div , make it position: absolute, width and height 100% and give it a color and opacity, put z-index so that its behind the image you want to give emphasis to. Now just fade in and out the div.

Why was your solution a big mess? Should be very straight forward.

Comment: Height will be fixed value. I can't use 100% for width, because it will scale my image. It should basically cut off an equal amount of the image on the right- and left-hand side. 

That's why I stopped using this method, I couldn't find a solution to fix this. I went ahead and searched for a JS alternative, which allowed me to use the "background" options. I thought this was better, as I want my banner to be a background.